# Combination of repeating letters

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have only $3$ letters ABC. Each letter can be repeated exactly $n$ times. Question: given a repeating time $n$, how many combinations are there?

For example: $n = 2$, the combinations can be

AABBCC, ABCABC, BBCCAA, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a given $n$, we form strings of length $3n$. We can create a string by selecting $n$ of the $3n$ letters to be A's, then choosing $n$ of the remaining $2n$ letters to be B's, and letting the rest be C's.

Recall that the binomial coefficient, which gives the number of ways to choose $k$ objects of $n$ possible selections without replacement in any order is given by:

$$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

The number of ways to choose $n$ of the $3n$ letters to be A'sand then choose $n$ of the remaining $2n$ letters to be B's is given by multiplying two binomial coefficients, since the number of ways to select B's does not depend on our selection of A's. Thus, the answer to the problem is given by:

$$
\begin{align}
\binom{3n}{n}\binom{2n}{n}&=\frac{(3n)!}{n!(3n-n)!}\frac{(2n)!}{n!(2n-n)!} \\
&= \frac{(3n)!(2n)!}{(n!)^3(2n)!} \\
&= \frac{(3n)!}{(n!)^3}
\end{align}$$

In your example, for $n=2$, the number of combinations is $\displaystyle\frac{6!}{(2!)^3}=90$.

We can do a quick "gut check" by verifying that the number of combinations for $n=1$ is $3!=6$, which is to be expected.

Comment: Thanks Jason! These are very helpful. Refreshed my math mind. One more question if you don't mind: within those combinations, how many of them contains substring "AXXBXXC" in order , e.g. AABBCC,ACBBAC, XAXXXBXXXCXXX are valid, and AACCBB,CCXXXX are not?